# Accessing google spreadsheet using shared link

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am building a python app where user can provide 'Anyone can edit' link to their spreadsheet and data can be read from there. I am using python's gspread module but it throws SpreadSheetNotFound error.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('myauth.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open_by_url(urls_given_by_user_having_edit_permission)
```

Above code is not working. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you share the `urls_given_by_user_having_edit_permission` format? Just to give a general idea of a value. You may omit some characters if you'd like to hide the real value.

Comment: @Burnash its like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0_Ao-U2Euub0_cadx44R3EPMpEC0KUJW-t3E where value after d/ is the key. I am searching for any way to get the above task done, not stringent on gspread.

Comment: did you try to open the spreadsheet by key? https://github.com/burnash/gspread#opening-a-spreadsheet

Comment: another possible solution is to access your spreadsheets via json interface: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<PUT-KEY-HERE>/od6/public/values?alt=json for list, and https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/<PUT-KEY-HERE>/od6/public/values?alt=json for cells

Comment: @Burnash by key extracts key from url, that's it and that didn't work as well. Feeds will give spreadsheets from out own account, isn't it? I was looking to access doc of another user that is shared with edit permission.

Comment: You're right, it won't work with public sheets. Only with private sheets _shared_ with client email address. Did you try accessing your spreadsheets with json api links?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

wks.share('', perm_type='anyone', role='reader')

Read permission for all people with link. reference https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.share